# How to convert a Splitting formula from Excel to Sheets (given that Textsplit is missing)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm attempting to copy the function of the following Excel sheet into Google Sheets and running into a snag.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApTGA-odt1HWhzGjuVHPn9bJyr5G?e=ZxtUCi

It takes the list from A2 chops them up into the number of groups requested in c3 and displays them randomly in the group columns. ( Yes I want to to recalculate when a change is made to the sheet)

the issue is the following formula uses a number of features Google Sheets does not have.

```
=LET(group_count,C2,input_names_as_rows,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A2,,",")),how_many_names,ROWS(input_names_as_rows),random_names_as_rows,SORTBY(input_names_as_rows,RANDARRAY(how_many_names)),rows_per_group_count,CEILING.MATH(how_many_names/group_count,1),BYCOL(MAKEARRAY(rows_per_group_count,group_count,LAMBDA(each_row,each_column,IFERROR(INDEX(random_names_as_rows,(each_row-1)*group_count+each_column,1),""))),LAMBDA(each_col,TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,each_col))))
```

Trying to use the formula gives the error

- Error Unknown function: 'TEXTSPLIT'

I attempted to use split (SPLIT(A2,","), and no values returned but also no errors.

I cannot use Excel for the things I need to do and need to keep the end result to two rows beyond that I'd prefer not to use an app script if there was any other way and I need it to recaluate when a value in the sheet changes.

I included both spreadsheets and would love any help anyone could give in fixing this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IRhfR7OkaoeTc5k7LJGysmndE1zQtfz22VSlMDUaFs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!   Links to outside spreadsheets are helpful but questions should include everything necessary to answer. Take the site [Tour] and review [ask].   Then [Edit] the question to include sample data and your expected result.  Convert copied cells/tables from Sheets to [proper markdown format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables). Tools like the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) can make this easier.  Include relevant formulas describing what did/didn't work including any errors you encountered.